# Best way to store drawable list

Tags: android, list, drawable

I'm trying to create a little game. Now, I'm writting a kind of "init" file.
Depending the level, I want to change the background (drawable). I have a class level and a method setBackgroung.

My setup file is build like that
-- 01 --           // level one
[BKG]:2130837520     // id of the drawable

-- 02 --           // level two
[BKG]:2130837525     // id of the drawable

I created a function to draw the background depending the level. It works, but I'm not sure that my solution is very nice. And I have for each level almost 20 different drawable

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why don't you use an SQLite database?

Answer (score 1):

If I were using default Android stuff I'd go with a [`LevelListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html).  Just set up your drawable in an xml file like this:

```
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/level_1" />
    <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/level_2" />
    <item android:maxLevel="2" android:drawable="@drawable/level_3" />
    <item android:maxLevel="3" android:drawable="@drawable/level_4" />
</level-list>
```

Then set that as your background.  As the player progresses just call

```
backgroundDrawable.setLevel(level);
```

and it will switch to the drawable associated with that level.  Then, as you add levels, you'll just need to add a line in the xml file.